# FZ300 Can I change the viewfinder and screen exposure?

Tags: exposure

I have a Panasonic DMC-FZ300, I set the camera in bracketing mode, then I reduced the exposure in such a way that the third picture is the one with the correct exposure. Trouble is that the viewfinder shows the exposure of the first picture, it is underexposed. When I have a lot of light behind me I find it a bit difficult to look into the viewfinder. If I have time I increase the exposure and before shooting I compensate it down again. But rarely I have time, I want to quickly catch the moment and most of the time I have to crop and adjust the frame in a post process.

Is there a way to increase the exposure shown in the viewfinder?

Comment: [*Visor*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visor)?

Comment: @MichaelC Perhaps a mistranslation of viewscreen/EVF... That's how I take it anyway.

Comment: @MichaelC BobT was right. It was a mistranslation. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

> ... I reduced the exposure in such a way that the third picture is the one with the correct exposure. Trouble is that the viewfinder shows the exposure of the first picture, it is underexposed.

Because it is underexposed. You dialed in underexposure.

> Is there a way to increase the exposure shown in the viewfinder?

Not really in this case. I would suggest that if you want to bracket with consistent underexposure but still see the "normal" exposure, that instead of dialing in compensation, you set your bracket to 5 frames instead of 3 and then simply discard the brighter images you didn't want in post.

Comment: I have already  set the bracketing to 5 frames. I rarely create an HDR out of my pictures. But when I do with 5 frames in the range -3, +1 working with Luminance I get the results I like the most.

Answer (score 1):

It's very normal for the electronic viewfinder to show the image with the compensation which you've set, be it in bracketing or in normal usage. If you would like to see normal image in the viewfinder you should find out how to shift the bracketing range downwards without changing exposure compensation. The manual I've found online is not very detailed, so try different dials and buttons to see if you can shift the bracketing range, it must be in the same place where you select it's size.

In worst case scenario the range cannot be shifted, then you can use raw files and tweak the colour settings to brighten the image. The raw file won't be affected in any way but the viewfinder preview and saved image will be brighter. I'm entirely not sure if this suits your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'Preview' mode is turned off. Preview mode displays the effects of exposure in the viewfinder. If you turn it off the viewfinder will display a brighter image without showing the effects of aperture or exposure. You can find the setting on page 89 of the manual but the TLDR is

[image]

Comment: It didn't work, but thank you for the answer anyway. For the moment I just increased the screen luminosity. It will suck the battery and it will make it difficult to check the correct exposure when reviewing the pictures after the shot, but it helps.

Comment: @FluidCode Can you not set the camera to take the series in this order: 0, -, + instead?

Comment: @MichaelC I wanted to take the pictures in the range -3,+1 so I set the bracketing range -2,+2 then I changed the default exposure to -1. So, actually it is not the brcketing the culprit, but the second setting.